# How to put class template into dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, class, templates, generics

I have some class template:

```
class SmartList<T> where T : SomeBaseClassForAllTs
{
    public void Add(T obj) { /*add something to somewhere*/ }
}
```

Also I have some amount of classes derived from `SomeBaseClassForAllTs`.
Somewhere my program receive instructions to create that class instances by their names as `string` (like `Car`, `Bus`, `Bicycle`, `Space ship`).

I have an `Dictionary<string, Type> str2type` to resolve which class instance to create.
I create classes through `Activator`:

```
object new_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(str2type[received_str]); //will create one of derived classes
```

Then I want to put that `new_obj` into one of `SmartList`s, but without making a lot of `if`s like that:

```
if (received_str == "Car")
    SmartListsStorage.CarsSmartList.Add(new_obj );
else if (received_str == "Bus")
    SmartListsStorage.BusesSmartList.Add(new_obj );
else if (...)
    ...
```

I want to have some kind of dictionary like that: `Dictionary<Type, SmartList> type2smlst` and use it like that: `type2smlst[new_obj.GetType()].Add(new_obj)`, but I can't declare such dictionary, because it says `Using the generic type 'SmartList<T>' requires 1 type arguments`.

What is possible to do?

Comment: the problem here is, that you have a set if information you provide at **runtime** but expect the **compiler** to know these, which generally is impossible. Generics are ment to be used in conjuction with **compile-time**-types.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Can I create some base class without `T` with virtual `Add` method, inherit SmartList<T> from it and then make dictionary like that: `Dictionary<Type, ThatBaseClass>`? Or maybe use interface instead of base class?

Comment: @Kosmo零 You can, or use an interface instead of a base class if that's more suitable

Comment: @canton7 - Ouch, seems like I can't, since I need `T` in `Add` parameters, but base class or interface shouldn't have `T`.

Comment: did you know new_obj <-- this type ?

Comment: One way is an `Add` method which accepts a `SomeBaseClassForAllTs`, then `SmartList<T>` can cast it. You're doing something which is sidestepping the runtime guarantees which generics offer you, so expect some uglyness!

Comment: @TimChang - Sorry, I don't understand your question. `new_obj` is the derived class instance created by `Activator`. I know it's string class name and it's `Type`.

Comment: @canton7 - I will try and see how it works. Thanks.